# how to keep ephemeral and riverpod state in sync (when using timers)

Tags: flutter, state, race-condition, riverpod

I'm trying to write a flutter application which lets you control multiple toys remotely using HTTP requests. The control elements are always visible, and the user can freely change between available toys by picking the active one from a list. Naturally this leads to the control elements having some local (ephemeral) state and all toys each having their individual state (I'm using riverpod here).

Now, the problem I'm having is keeping those two states in sync. When rapidly switching between toys in the list, it randomly happens that the state of one gets overwritten by that of another. So apparently I've created some form of race condition here:

[image: race condition]

I'm using riverpods [ref.listen](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-reflisten-to-react-to-a-provider-change) to update ephemeral state when the currently active toy changes, and a periodically triggered timer to update the toy's state from the ephemeral state. My best guess (without fully understanding darts execution model) is that the lambda function executed by ref.listen and the timer callback get executed in such a way that the old local state gets sent to the new selected toy or the other way round.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:word_generator/word_generator.dart';

part 'main.g.dart';

// ignore: constant_identifier_names
const int NUMBER_OF_TOYS = 4;

// Class representing our remote controlled toy
class Toy {
  final String name;
  final double speed;
  const Toy(this.name, this.speed);
}

// Using an (Async)NotifierProvider to manage a list of toys
@riverpod
class Toys extends _$Toys {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<Toy>> build() async {
    return List.generate(
        NUMBER_OF_TOYS, (index) => Toy(WordGenerator().randomNoun(), 0));
  }

  Future<void> updateToy(int index, Toy toy) async {
    assert(index <= NUMBER_OF_TOYS);

    // Fake some delay to simulate HTTP request
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));

    // Update state
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      return [
        for (var i = 0; i < state.requireValue.length; ++i)
          if (i == index) toy else state.requireValue[i],
      ];
    });
  }
}

// Provider giving us the index of the currently selected toy index (or null)
final selectedToyIndexProvider = StateProvider<int?>((_) => null);

// Provider giving us the currently selected toy (or null)
@riverpod
Toy? selectedToy(SelectedToyRef ref) {
  final toys = ref.watch(toysProvider);
  final selectedIndex = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider);
  return selectedIndex != null ? toys.requireValue[selectedIndex] : null;
}

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final selectedIndex = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider);
    final toys = ref.watch(toysProvider);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Toy control',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: toys.when(
        data: (data) {
          return Row(children: [
            Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TOYS; ++i)
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Toy "${data[i].name}"'),
                      subtitle: Text('${data[i].speed}'),
                      onTap: () => ref
                          .read(selectedToyIndexProvider.notifier)
                          .update((state) => selectedIndex != i ? i : null),
                      selected: selectedIndex == i,
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            selectedIndex != null ? const MySlider() : const Placeholder(),
          ]);
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          return const Placeholder();
        },
        loading: () {
          return const Placeholder();
        },
      )),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MySlider extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MySlider({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MySlider> createState() => _MySliderState();
}

class _MySliderState extends ConsumerState<MySlider> {
  late final Timer _timer;
  late double _speed;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final toy = ref.read(selectedToyProvider);
    _speed = toy!.speed;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), _timerCallack);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Update ephemeral state if toy index changes and not null
    ref.listen(selectedToyIndexProvider, (previous, next) {
      if (next == null || previous == next) return;
      final toy = ref.watch(selectedToyProvider);
      setState(() {
        _speed = toy!.speed;
      });
    });

    return Slider(
      value: _speed,
      onChanged: (speed) => setState(() {
        _speed = speed;
      }),
    );
  }

  // Use a timer callback to periodically update toy state
  void _timerCallack(_) {
    final selectedIndex = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider);
    final toy = ref.read(selectedToyProvider)!;
    if (selectedIndex != null) {
      ref.read(toysProvider.notifier).updateToy(
            selectedIndex,
            Toy(toy.name, _speed),
          );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry to be that guy, but DON'T DO THIS. Please. Keeping multiple state management approaches is a terrible idea. Can you explain why you initially picked this approach so that we can solve that problem instead? Why can't you just use `ref.watch()` and `ref.read()`? If you don't know exactly, that's ok, I will suggest how I would do what you want to do

Comment: As far as I can tell I haven't "picked multiple state management approaches". The GUI needs some local data to react on and or draw from. Of course I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Note that you must use `ref.read` in the `_MySliderState` widget instead of `ref.watch(selectedToyProvider)` in `build->in ref.listen` and instead of `ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider)` in `_timerCallack`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that's not the cause of the issue though is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was finally able to identify where the race condition actually occurs. Turns out riverpod providers don't update atomically. If you have two providers where one depends on the other, you can't rely on both providers getting updated at the same time.

In my example this happens at the "convenience" provider which gets you the currently active toy from a list of toys depending on the selected index:

```dart
@riverpod
Toy? selectedToy(SelectedToyRef ref) {
  final toys = ref.watch(toysProvider);
  final selectedIndex = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider);
  return selectedIndex != null ? toys.requireValue[selectedIndex] : null;
}
```

When listening to changes to the current index, it might happen that inside the callback where you'd expect a different toy, the toy provider actually gets you the old one from the previous index:

```dart
ref.listen(selectedToyIndexProvider, (previous, next) {
  if (next == null || previous == next) return;
  final toy = ref.watch(selectedToyProvider);
  setState(() {
    _speed = toy!.speed;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would consider using freezed, I just went ahead to simplify my debugging. I also simplified your methods.

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:word_generator/word_generator.dart';

import 'main.dart';

part 'toy.freezed.dart';
part 'toy.g.dart';

@freezed
class Toy with _$Toy {
  const factory Toy({
    required String name,
    required double speed,
  }) = _Toy;
}

@riverpod
class Toys extends _$Toys {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<Toy>> build() async {
    return List.unmodifiable(List.generate(
      numberOfToys,
      (_) => Toy(name: WordGenerator().randomNoun(), speed: 0),
    ));
  }

  Future<void> updateToy(int index, Toy toy) async {
    assert(index <= numberOfToys);

    // Fake some delay to simulate HTTP request
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));

    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async => List.unmodifiable([...state.requireValue]..[index] = toy));
  }
}
```

Then, you do not need to mix ephemeral state, just go ahead and use riverpod entirely:

```dart
class MySlider extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MySlider({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final toy = ref.watch(selectedToyProvider)!;
    final index = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider)!;
    return Slider(
      value: toy.speed,
      onChanged: (speed) => ref.read(toysProvider.notifier).updateToy(index, toy.copyWith(speed: speed)),
    );
  }
}

@riverpod
Toy? selectedToy(SelectedToyRef ref) {
  final toys = ref.watch(toysProvider);
  final selectedIndex = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider);
  return selectedIndex != null ? toys.requireValue[selectedIndex] : null;
}

final selectedToyIndexProvider = StateProvider<int?>((_) => null);
```

Here is the whole main.dart. Hope this helps.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:test_project/toy.dart';

part 'main.g.dart';

const int numberOfToys = 4;

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final selectedIndex = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider);
    final toys = ref.watch(toysProvider);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Toy control',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: toys.when(
          data: (data) => Row(children: [
              Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfToys; ++i)
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Toy "${data[i].name}"'),
                        subtitle: Text('${data[i].speed}'),
                        onTap: () => ref
                            .read(selectedToyIndexProvider.notifier)
                            .update((state) => selectedIndex != i ? i : null),
                        selected: selectedIndex == i,
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              selectedIndex != null ? const MySlider() : const Placeholder(),
            ]),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => const Placeholder(),
          loading: () => const Placeholder(),
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MySlider extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MySlider({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final toy = ref.watch(selectedToyProvider)!;
    final index = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider)!;
    return Slider(
      value: toy.speed,
      onChanged: (speed) => ref.read(toysProvider.notifier).updateToy(index, toy.copyWith(speed: speed)),
    );
  }
}

@riverpod
Toy? selectedToy(SelectedToyRef ref) {
  final toys = ref.watch(toysProvider);
  final selectedIndex = ref.watch(selectedToyIndexProvider);
  return selectedIndex != null ? toys.requireValue[selectedIndex] : null;
}

final selectedToyIndexProvider = StateProvider<int?>((_) => null);
```

Now, this does remove the timer, if you only want to do the http request periodically, consider a Timer independent from any widget that reads the provider and does the http work. This will be a lot less messy and independent from user interaction which can lead to unpredictable side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far (specially the simplifications). The project where my question originated from is already using freeze. I'd also prefer not to use a timer but I fear I won't have any other option. Directly sending a HTTP request on every "onChanged" event is suffocating my device. In addition, some of the toy's parameters need to be polled anyway (e.g. an error condition, overcurrent on some motor, stuff like that). But I don't see where it would be best to use the timer. How is this supposed to work without additional local state?

Comment: Minor other "flaw" of the "direct approach" is that it would absolutely require optimistic updates. One would have to modify state before doing the HTTP request otherwise the GUI gets very unresponsive.

Comment: As I said, move the http request into a method reading your provider and add a timer outside the widget tree.